# date not parsing correct in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch,My index "records" and type "records".This index type contains some documents.
Structure of index type mapping

```
"mappings": {

    "records": {
        "date_detection": false,
        "properties": {
            "dateModified": {
                "format": "dd/mm/yyyy",
                "type": "date"
            },
            "org": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My documents are

```
{
    "org": "pm",
    "dateModified": "01/12/2015"
},
{
    "org": "muthuraj",
    "dateModified": "10/01/2013"

},
{
    "org": "user",
    "dateModified": "12/05/2015"

},
 {
    "org": "satish",
    "dateModified": "2/05/2014"

}
```

and I write query to get document dateModified > "02/05/2013"

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "records.dateModified": {
                            "gt": "02/05/2013"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and I get result  like
{

```
"took": 14,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "records",
            "_type": "records",
            "_id": "NXD8t3TSQxev2WMcNTdchQ",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "org": "pm",
                "dateModified": "01/12/2015"
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "_index": "records",
            "_type": "records",
            "_id": "vyxdivH8RLujCFSNWMQTdg",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "org": "muthuraj",
                "dateModified": "10/01/2013"
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "_index": "records",
            "_type": "records",
            "_id": "QqDTULhwSqOGykYCOOrcHw",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "org": "user",
                "dateModified": "12/05/2015"
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "_index": "records",
            "_type": "records",
            "_id": "btPGMDPgRPimNgLHK2y2OA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "org": "satish",
                "dateModified": "2/05/2014"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

"dateModified": "10/01/2013" This is less than "2/05/2015" but this also getting in result why it is coming like this.
How to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `"format": "dd/mm/yyyy"`. ES thinks `mm` refers to minutes, so you need to use `MM`. I've always found date formatting in ES to be a little confusing and not very well-documented, but it's quite powerful. You might take a look at this [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html).

Using the second version of your question, I can set up an index like this:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "records": {
         "date_detection": false,
         "properties": {
            "dateModified": {
               "format": "dd/MM/yyyy",
               "type": "date"
            },
            "org": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

POST /test_index/records/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"org": "pm","dateModified": "01/12/2015"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"org": "muthuraj","dateModified": "10/01/2013"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"org": "user","dateModified": "12/05/2015"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"org": "satish","dateModified": "2/05/2014"}
```

Then the query works as expected:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "range": {
                  "records.dateModified": {
                     "gt": "02/05/2013"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "records",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "org": "pm",
               "dateModified": "01/12/2015"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "records",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "org": "user",
               "dateModified": "12/05/2015"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "records",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "org": "satish",
               "dateModified": "2/05/2014"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the code:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/24e468f010ef9323e5974b1e0534c755cb097cfd

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with what you posted (your mapping isn't structured properly, and the document you posted would not be returned by your query in any case), but maybe those are just artifacts of the way you posted your question.

What you're trying to do worked for me. First I created a simple index with your mapping (properly structured, with type name `"doc"`):

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "date_detection": false,
         "properties": {
            "dateCreated": {
               "properties": {
                  "date": {
                     "type": "date",
                     "format": "dd/mm/yyyy"
                  },
                  "time": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            },
            "dateModified": {
               "type": "date",
               "format": "dd/mm/yyyy"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then indexed a couple of documents:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "Project": "02ff5704273e",
   "ProjectSpace": "tigerPark",
   "relationDesc": [
      "Project-hasSpace-recordId",
      "recordId-forProject-Project"
   ],
   "org": "user",
   "docType": "ProjectSpace",
   "dateCreated": {
      "date": "22/05/2015",
      "time": "18:28 IST"
   },
   "dateModified": "22/05/2015",
   "revision": 1
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
   "Project": "02ff5704273e",
   "ProjectSpace": "tigerPark",
   "relationDesc": [
      "Project-hasSpace-recordId",
      "recordId-forProject-Project"
   ],
   "org": "user",
   "docType": "ProjectSpace",
   "dateCreated": {
      "date": "30/05/2015",
      "time": "18:28 IST"
   },
   "dateModified": "30/05/2015",
   "revision": 1
}
```

Then when I ran your query, the correct document was returned:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "range": {
         "dateModified": {
            "gt": "28/05/2015"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 29,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "Project": "02ff5704273e",
               "ProjectSpace": "tigerPark",
               "relationDesc": [
                  "Project-hasSpace-recordId",
                  "recordId-forProject-Project"
               ],
               "org": "user",
               "docType": "ProjectSpace",
               "dateCreated": {
                  "date": "30/05/2015",
                  "time": "18:28 IST"
               },
               "dateModified": "30/05/2015",
               "revision": 1
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So your problem would appear to be somewhere else. I don't think it matters here, but I used Elasticsearch 1.5.1.

Here is all the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/2a97abc1530060b02f3b1a68ab81e5cd84bff915

Comment: I updated my post see once.I given my index type mapping and query

Comment: Again, what you posted works for me. The query you posted contains the date `"gt": "02/05/2013"`, and all four documents have dates greater than that, so all are returned. When I changed the date in the query to "gt": "02/05/2014", only the appropriate two documents were returned. Here is the code I used to test your second version: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/740322d0f27f20fc1161686615eb87c18b66a43a

Comment: Observe one thing "dateModified": "10/01/2013" is less than given date "02/05/2013".If I give this date ,result has only 3 documents.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was thinking in American dates. I found the problem though. I'll post a new answer.